# Orientation of camera not preserved when switching between camera types in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

[All of the code](https://repl.it/@guymichaely/tesselator3D)

Hello, I'm having a problem with switching between a perspective camera and an orthographic camera. My goal is to be able to have a switch to easily switch back and forth between the two camera types while preserving the camera's location and orientation. Here's the relevant code (line 98):

```
let display = gui.addFolder("Display");
display.add(guiOptions.display,"orthographicCamera").name("Orthographic Camera").onChange(function(){
  var position=camera.position;
  var target=controls.target;
  var quaternion=camera.quaternion;
  if (guiOptions.display.orthographicCamera){
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
      window.innerWidth / - (zoom / scaleFactor),
      window.innerWidth / (zoom / scaleFactor),
      window.innerHeight / (zoom / scaleFactor),
      window.innerHeight / - (zoom / scaleFactor),
      -500, 1000);
  }
  else{
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 115, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.000001, 10000 );
  }
  camera.position.set(position.x,position.y,position.z);
  camera.quaternion.set(quaternion._x,quaternion._y,quaternion._z,quaternion._w);
  controls=new THREE.TrackballControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = .15;
  controls.target=target;
});
```

My problem is that, for some camera rotations, the switch between a perspective camera and an orthographic camera results in a different orientation of the resulting camera. I thought it was a problem with the quaternion attribute, but changing it to its previous value doesn't seem to have any effect.

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this. I'd appreciate any help, thanks ahead of time!

EDIT: I figured it out but I'm doing something right now, so I'll update with my solution later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
orthoCamera=orthographic camera instance
orthoControls=document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
orthoControls=new THREE.TrackballControls(orthoCamera,renderer.domElement);
perspectiveCamera=perpsective camera instance
perspectiveControls=new THREE.TrackballControls(perspectiveCamera,renderer.domElement);
...
display.add(guiOptions.display,"orthoCamera").name("Orthographic Camera");
...
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orthoControls.update();
    perspectiveControls.update();
    if (guiOptions.display.orthoCamera){
        renderer.render(scene, orthoCamera)
    }
    else{
        renderer.render(scene, perspectiveCamera)
    }
}
```

Thus both controls are active at the same time, and switching between camera views is simply a switch between witch camera to render with.